# pointer to string concept in c

Tags: c, string, pointers

Can anybody tell me that the following declaration is correct or not:

```
char (*p)[10];
```

`p` is a pointer to a string of 10 characters.

I made a program as below:

```
/*PROGRAM*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void xstrcpy(char (**)[], const char (**)[]);
void main()
{
    const char (*xsource)[10]="SUPERB";

    char (*xtarget)[10];

    printf("\n\n*************PART1*************\n\n");   
    printf("%s\n",xsource);

    printf("\n\n*************PART2*************\n\n");

    xtarget=xsource;

    printf("%s\n",xtarget);

    printf("\n\n*************PART3*************\n\n");


    xstrcpy(xtarget,xsource);
    puts(xtarget);

}

void xstrcpy(char (**p)[],const char (**q)[])
{

        p=q;
}
```

The purpose of program is to copy a string from another.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://cdecl.org is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

To learn how to determine variable types in C, you should learn the 'right-left rule' which is explained here: http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html

Using the rule, and following the style of the ieng9 article here's how you can determine the type in your example:

```
1. Find identifier                      char (*p)[10];
                                               ^
   "p is a"

2. Move right (stop at right paren)     char (*p)[10];
                                                ^
3. Stop at right paren and move left    char (*p)[10];
                                              ^
   "p is a pointer to"

4. Stop at left paren and move right    char (*p)[10];
                                                 ^
   "p is a pointer to array (size 10) of"

5. Out of symbols so move left          char (*p)[10];
                                        ^
   "p is a pointer to array (size 10) of char"
```

Or in other words, p is a pointer to a char array of size 10.

Answer (score 1):

> p is a pointer to a string of 10 characters.

It's a pointer to a `char` array of length-10, which may or may not be interpreted as a string...

Answer (score 0):

char (*p)[10];

A good way to explain this code is to read from right to left, in fact, it is the real way to understand this code in compilation.

So the process is: `[10]` -> this is an array with 10 elements. 
                   `(*p)[10]` -> this is a pointer to an array with 10 whatever type elements.
                   `char (*p)[10]` -> this is a pointer to an array with 10 char elements.

Here we could find if we don't have brackets, we will meet `p[10]` firstly and the final result will become a little different: the p is an array firstly instead of a pointer.

You could read one article wrote by Dan Sales: const T vs. T const. It will help you a lot in understanding this kind of problem, though it focuses on c++.

For your program, I can only say please make a experiment and post your result, thank you firstly ^0^ ~~ if you let me guess, I think I will say it would not work because the type of pointer is wrong.